# Why printf() don't gives any error and issue with scanf()

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Code:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int y,i;
  printf("Number of character you entered is : %d",printf("you entered age : %d\n",i,scanf("%d",&i),printf("Enter age : "))-19);
  printf("\n\n");
  scanf("%d ",&y,printf("Enter number(y) : "));
  printf("Value of y is %d",y);
}
```

Here are two statements ,
In first statement I want to ask why `printf()` don't give any error or warning?

```
printf("Number of character you entered is : %d",printf("you entered age : %d\n",i,scanf("%d",&i),printf("Enter age : "))-19);
```

Second statement when executing is asking for input two times, first time after

> "Enter number(y) : "

after entering number it ask for another input , don't know why.

And value of `y` is the value you entered first time so what's the matter behind  second input ?

```
scanf("%d ",&y,printf("Enter number(y) : "));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why should there be an error or warning?

Comment: do you actually know what you're doing? IMHO, this code is not human readable.

Comment: Both `printf()` and `scanf()` return integer values, so there's nothing wrong with the syntax. The parameters of your `printf()` statements have to be evaluated before the function is called, so that explains the order of events. But this is really horrible code.

Comment: This code is awesome ! No obfuscation needed !!

Comment: Yup, another candidate for the lowest fail grade or unemployment benefit.

Comment: OP, note well: 'I wrote some clever-looking code', is very often followed by 'I cannot debug my code'.  That's why you are getting those comments from Sourav etc - they're tired of seeing 'clever' code posted on here.  If it's too clever for you to understand what is happening, why should anyone else bother?

Comment: I was just doing experiments on printf like printf inside printf and printf inside scanf and i was curious to know how printf manage all these stuff ! That's why i posted this question. This code is human readable !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first `printf()` statement, quoting `C11` standard, chapter 7.21.6.1, `fprintf()`

> If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are
>   evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

So, there is no error generated.

in case of `scanf()`, the issue is with

```
 scanf("%d ",&y,printf("Enter number(y) : "));
          ^
          |
```

the trailing white-space after the format specifier. Basically it tells to ignore *any number of trailing white-space* after the first input matching the conversion specifier. Upon encountering the a non-white-space character, it would actually complete *scanning*.

Quoting chapter §7.21.6.2

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread),.....

**solution:** remove the trailing white-space after the conversion specifier.

```
scanf("%d",&y,printf("Enter number(y) : "));
```

---

FWIW, even in case of having the excess argument than the conversion specifiers in the format string is defined behavour, as per `C11`, chapter 7.21.6.2

> If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

this is a *horrible* way to write a code.

Comment: Thnx !! , problem sloved

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't ask input "two times" rather `scanf()` is waiting for you to input a non-space whitespace character to terminate the input reading because of the extra space you have in the format string: `"%d "`.

A whitespace directive in scanf() will read and discard any number of whitespace characters. Hence, you are forced to input a non-whitespace character:

scanf [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) states:

> ·      A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline,
>                 etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of
>                 white space, including none, in the input.

In any case, you are passing too many arguments to `scanf()` than the format specifiers you pass and this is a terrible way of passing printing and scanning inputs a single statement.